# How to visualise the trajectories after LCGA with lcmm package

Tags: r

I have performed a LCGA with the lcmm package in R. A model with 3 classes and a quadratic form turned out to have the best fit. Now I want to visualise this model, so I want to see which participants are i which class and I want to see the trajectories of each class. I cannot find how to do this anywhere.

I used the following code in R to assess the optimal number and polynomial form.

```
# Create dataframe 
elsi1_cc_lcga <- select(elsi1_cc, id, subjective_childhood, own_education, subjective_adulthood)


# Reshape data frame from wide to long format for LCGA
elsi1_cc_long <- tidyr::pivot_longer(elsi1_cc_lcga, cols = -id, names_to = "time", values_to = "SEP")

elsi1_cc_long$time <- (rec(elsi1_cc_long$time, rec = "subjective_childhood=1; own_education=2; subjective_adulthood=3"))


## Analysis
set.seed(1234)


# assess optimal number of groups
lcga1_normal <- hlme(SEP ~ time + I(time^2), subject = "id", random=~1, ng = 1, data = elsi1_cc_long)

lcga2_normal <- gridsearch(rep = 100, maxiter = 10, minit = lcga1_normal,
                           m = hlme(SEP ~ time + I(time^2), subject = "id", random=~1,
                                    ng = 2, data = elsi1_cc_long, mixture = ~ time + I(time^2)))
lcga3_normal <- gridsearch(rep = 100, maxiter = 10, minit = lcga1_normal,
                           m = hlme(SEP ~ time + I(time^2), subject = "id", random=~1,
                                    ng = 3, data = elsi1_cc_long, mixture = ~ time + I(time^2)))
lcga4_normal <- gridsearch(rep = 100, maxiter = 10, minit = lcga1_normal,
                           m = hlme(SEP ~ time + I(time^2), subject = "id", random=~1,
                                    ng = 4, data = elsi1_cc_long, mixture = ~ time + I(time^2)))
lcga5_normal <- gridsearch(rep = 100, maxiter = 10, minit = lcga1_normal,
                           m = hlme(SEP ~ time + I(time^2), subject = "id", random=~1,
                                    ng = 5, data = elsi1_cc_long, mixture = ~ time + I(time^2)))


# assess optimal polynomial function 
lcga6_normal <- hlme(SEP ~ time, subject = "id", random=~1, ng = 3, mixture = ~ 1, 
                     data = elsi1_cc_long, B= c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1))

lcga7_normal <- hlme(SEP ~ time + I(time^2), subject = "id", random=~1, ng = 3, 
                     mixture = ~ time + I(time^2), data = elsi1_cc_long, B = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1))

lcga8_normal <- hlme(SEP ~ time + I(time^2) + I(time^3), subject = "id", random=~1, ng = 3, 
                     mixture = ~ time + I(time^2) + I(time^3), data = elsi1_cc_long, B = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1))
```

I tried several funtions of the lcmm package but they do not seem to work. Can anyone help me to visualise my classes and trajectories?